# Can silicone moulds be used for making cupcakes in electric tandoor

Tags: baking, equipment, cupcakes

I am preparing cupcakes as I have bought new electric tandoor. Now I am confused,  can silicone moulds be used in electric tandoor or not?

Comment: An electric tandoor seems to be a juxtaposition since a tandoor cooks by putting food within the fire itself. I am guessing an electric tandoor is meant to be too hot for a silicon baking mold.

Comment: What is the temperature of the tandoor?  Silicone molds tend to list a max temp between 425°F and 500°F (215°C to 260°C)

Comment: What is the brand/model of the electric tandoor? If you have adjustable heat settings you should be able to use the molds and bake cupcakes. If you don't have adjustable heat settings it might be difficult to bake cupcakes anyway, they need a milder heat (around 180C) than a classic tandoor would give.

Comment: I'm using smart life mini tandoor can I use Silicon mould for baking cupcakes?

Answer (score 1):

SilPat, a brand of silicone baking pads, is certified to 480°F. I don’t know about “electric” tandoors, but traditional tandoors, even the DIY kind, generally are much hotter than this.

So, If your tandoor can’t cook at considerably reduced temperatures, your silicone cupcake molds will not be effective. I don’t think your cupcakes would stand that kind of heat either, as a commenter already pointed out!y